# MPMoviePlayerController with no content (iOS 5) - The Operation Could Not Be Completed

Tags: iphone, video, video-capture, ios5

I have problem with `MPMoviePlayerController` (`self.mp`). When I want to access `duration` property, I get `0`, when I want to access `thumbnail…`, I get `nil`. On iOS 4 it is OK, iOS 5 it is not.

After all app says to me: The Operation Could Not Be Completed.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    if([[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]){
        NSString *tempFilePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];


        NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        double hashToNameOfFile = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] * 1000.0;
        NSString *finalPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.0f.%@", hashToNameOfFile, @"MOV"]];
        NSString *finalPathToThumbRetina = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"thumb_%.0f@2x.%@", hashToNameOfFile, @"jpg"]];
        NSString *finalPathToThumb = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"thumb_%.0f.%@", hashToNameOfFile, @"jpg"]];

        // we do need retina now, we use real name for CoreData
        NSString *finalImage = [finalPath lastPathComponent];
        NSString *finalImageThumb = [finalPathToThumb lastPathComponent];


        if ( UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(tempFilePath)){
            // Copy it to the camera roll.
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(tempFilePath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), tempFilePath);
        }

        // save video to application directory
        NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:tempFilePath];
        if ( [videoData writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES] ) {
            NSLog(@"SAVED");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"NOT SAVED");
        }


        // create thumbnail of video
        MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:finalPath]];
        self.mp = moviePlayer;
        [moviePlayer release];

        NSData *videoData2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
        NSLog(@"LENGTH %i", [videoData2 length]);


        NSLog(@"FINAL PATH %@", finalPath);
        UIImage *image = [[[UIImage alloc] init] autorelease];
        image = [self.mp thumbnailImageAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
        NSLog(@"%@", [image size]);
        UIImage *thumbImageRetina = [image thumbnailImage:400 transparentBorder:0 cornerRadius:0 interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];
        UIImage *thumbImage = [image thumbnailImage:200 transparentBorder:0 cornerRadius:0 interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationDefault];
        NSData *thumbImageRetinaData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbImageRetina, 1.0)];
        NSData *thumbImageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbImage, 1.0)];
        if ( [thumbImageRetinaData writeToFile:finalPathToThumbRetina atomically:YES] ) {
            NSLog(@"RETINA THUMB SAVED");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"RETINA THUMB NOT SAVED");
        }
        if ( [thumbImageData writeToFile:finalPathToThumb atomically:YES] ) {
            NSLog(@"THUMB SAVED");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"THUMB NOT SAVED");
        }

        // duration of video
        double dur = [self.mp duration];
        NSLog(@"DUR %f", dur);


        TaleRecords *newTaleRecord = (TaleRecords *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TaleRecords" inManagedObjectContext:_context];

        newTaleRecord.content = finalImage;
        newTaleRecord.date = [NSDate date];
        NSDecimalNumber *latNum = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:[self.latitude doubleValue]];
        NSDecimalNumber *longNum = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:[self.longitude doubleValue]];
        newTaleRecord.latitude = latNum; // vertical
        newTaleRecord.longitude = longNum; // horizontal
        [latNum release];
        [longNum release];
        newTaleRecord.contentType = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"cTypeVideo"];
        newTaleRecord.thumb = finalImageThumb;
        newTaleRecord.duration = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:dur];

        newTaleRecord.tale = tales;
        tales.record = [newTaleRecord tale].record;

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![_context save:&error]) {
            /*
             Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

             abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
             */
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }


    [CLController.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**More simple example**

I am doing this:

```
// save video to application directory
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:tempFilePath];
if ( [videoData writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES] ) {
   NSLog(@"SAVED");
}
else{
   NSLog(@"NOT SAVED");
}
```

At `tempFilePath` is real video content and I write it to `finalPath`. After that I create `MPMoviePlayerController` instance:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:finalPath]];
self.mp = moviePlayer;
[moviePlayer release];
```

But `self.mp` give me no content. When I want to do `[self.mp duration]`, it returns `zero/nil`. Path to resource works, but it seems no content is there.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It would definitely help if you provided a more simplified example...might help you as well!

Comment: OK, I have added **More simple example**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out my problem.
It is like iOS5 is not comfortable with:

```
 NSString *tempFilePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
```

so instead, if you just use

```
NSURL *someUrl =[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] ;
```

and then initial mpmovieplayercontroller with this url, it works fine for me,
which is exactly the opposite of iOS4.

here is my code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{



    mediaURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];   
    NSLog(@"%@",mediaURL);
    if (!mymoviePlayer) {
        mymoviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:mediaURL];
        [mymoviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
        [mymoviePlayer.view setFrame: videoView.bounds];
        [videoView addSubview:mymoviePlayer.view];
    }
    else
    {

        [mymoviePlayer setContentURL:mediaURL];
        [mymoviePlayer stop];
        [mymoviePlayer setInitialPlaybackTime:-1];
    }

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];   


}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I need. I have other problems with video on iOS5, but this is the biggest. Thank you again.

Comment: Argh! Had the same issue as you and took me ages to figure out that MPMoviePlayerController doesn't like certain NSURLs even though they are deemed as valid objects by the system. The "secret" is to get the file path as NSString and then use `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:URLStringPath]`

Comment: Rog's comment is the accurate answer.